# Git says "new commits" but none can be found in the folder

Tags: git

Strange thing that I couldn't find an answer for. I don't really know how this happens only that it does for the past couple of weeks.

I keep seeing a folder that has "***(new commits)***" at the end when I do `git status` but I'm sure I've done no changes to it. Also, when I `cd` into the folder and do `git status` from there, git tells me there are no changes present.

When I do commit this folder, I'm ok for a day or two, then it comes back. Could be that it comes back after I do a `git pull`, as it's a shared project and I didn't really check this behaviour yet.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This indicates that the `mockery` directory is a submodule, you have created new commits in the directory, and you have not updated the repository containing the submodule to point to the latest commit in the submodule's repository.  Note that submodules point to specific commits in a repository, not just some remote repository URL.  This ensures that when you clone a repository containing submodules, you get the *exact same code* that the author was using (or that the author declared he was using -- as you can see here, it's possible not to tell the "parent" repository about the new commits).

`git add mockery` will instruct Git to use the current `HEAD` commit in the submodule as the submodule's commit identifier.  This is a versioned change, so you will have to commit the result.

Comment: so when I add mockery and commit it, I should stop seeing this? because that's what we tried to do several times now but this thingy keeps coming back (although I was switching branches, so maybe it wasn't added in one of them but was in the other one...)

Comment: @ZathrusWriter You will stop seeing it until `HEAD` in the `mockery` directory points somewhere else.  For example, if within `mockery` you create a new commit or check out a different branch.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, give me 2 mins to accept the answer now :D